# How to fetch data for specific User in Firebase/React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Got my Landing page in here with hardcoded username / password into firebase db.

after successful login, I am redirected to the homepage. However, I am trying to figure out how to fetch the data for the specific logged in user. Currently, in my Firebase I have only 1 Collection which is Users and contains some documents any of the documents has their own fields it is all hardcoded for the sake of the test.

After the log in I am currently logging data but I only see the last added document. How do i attach the User to see its own data. I tried creating directly in firebase a document with the same UID as the logging user but the data that i am logging is still the last added document instead of the right for the specific user.

```
function LandingPage(props) {

    const [showErrorModal, setShow] = useState(false);
    const emailInputRef = useRef();
    const passwordInputRef = useRef();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function sumbitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
        const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;
        const url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyCNBAxjeKNoAPPjBV0JW4vZ0QaTaOx9-L4';
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: enteredEmail,
                password: enteredPassword,
                returnSecureToken: true,
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                
                navigate('/homepage')
            } else {
                setShow(true);
            }
            return res.json()
        }).then((data) =>
            console.log(data))
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setShow(false)
    }

    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <form onSubmit={sumbitForm}>
                <h3>Login Here</h3>
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sigh up with email" id="username" ref={emailInputRef} ></input>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" ref={passwordInputRef}></input>
                <button className='button' type="submit" typeof='submit' >Log In</button>
                {showErrorModal ? <Modal show={showErrorModal} onHide={handleClose}
                    backdrop="static">
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>Incorrect Username/Password</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        Please provide the correct credentials
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal> : null}
                <div className='landingpage-logo'>
                    <img src={logo} className="landingpage-logo"></img>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LandingPage;




import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { db, firebase } from '../../firebase';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {

    const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState([]);
    const username = props.email.substring(0, props.email.indexOf('@'))

    useEffect(() => {
        readData();
    }, [])

    async function readData() {
        db.collection('Users').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(element => {
                const incomingData = element.data();
                setLoadedData(incomingData)        
            })
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles['wrapper']}>
           
        </div>


    )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: This is an antipattern and you should use firebase Auth instead of hard coding user/pass and let firebase take care of the auth part for you.

If you want the user to get their own profile this is how you should do it.

1. Add firebase auth user/pass https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0

2. Use cloud function to listen for when a user has created an account https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events?hl=en&authuser=0

3. let cloud function create an document with that users Id.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple project in react by using firebase to use crud proccessing.

https://github.com/celalaygar/web-push/tree/master/react-firebase-CRUD-example

in package.json->dependencies :   `"firebase": "^7.14.1"`

in this file fetch data method is here.
https://github.com/celalaygar/web-push/blob/master/react-firebase-CRUD-example/src/components/main.component.js

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const data = await db.collection("spell").get();
    result = data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
    this.setState({ spell: result }); 
}
```